# Is there a javascript function that I can make to give radiobuttons a value?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

So I have a small issue with getting some values on radiobuttons. I've made a foreach loop in where the html makes radiobuttons. These are Yes/No buttons and Each yes/no set needs a value.

Like question 1 will have value 1, 2 will have 2, 3 will have 4, 4 will have 8 etc.

In the end it needs to add up to a total score,  BUT if NO is selected (eg. question 4 with value of 8 is NO, then the value becomes 0)

Ive tried doing a Javascript function shown below that makes it sort of work. But if all answers are NO and you make question 4 YES(which should have a value of 8) then it just says that my value is 2. I knew that this wouldnt work but I'm wondering if I can change this in a way that I can make it work the way that I want to

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="box">
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question)</p>
        <label>
            <input id="yes" type="radio" name="@item.Id" checked="">
            <span class=" yes randobtn">Ja</span>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input id="no" type="radio" name="@item.Id">
             <span class="no randobtn">Nee</span>
        </label>
     </div>
}




 <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="GetCount()">check</button>

@section Scripts{

     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click',
            '#btn',
            function() {
                console.log('test');
                location.href = "/Symptom/GetProblems?TotalPoints=" + 
count;
            });
        var count = 1;

        $(document).on('click',
            '.randobtn',
            function() {
                GetCount();
            });

        function GetCount() {
            var checkedRadioBtns = $('input[type="radio"]:checked');
            count = 1;

            for (var i = 0; i < checkedRadioBtns.length; i++) {
                if (checkedRadioBtns[i].id === 'no') {
                    console.log('in de if');
                    continue;
                } else {
                    count = count * 2;
                }
            }
            alert(count);
        }
    </script>
}
```

This is what I want: http://prntscr.com/o6zrqd
But as you can see in the alert it just says 1 when NO is selected

Comment: Why not just put a `value` attribute on the radio buttons when you create them?

Answer (score 0):

put value of true and false in the array
 and then 
value="@item.true_value"